# 2 External Lists Can't be together in the same Site Collection

Tags: external-list

This 2 external lists are different projects, which developed by VS 2012. So when I deploy one of them, they have to not effect eachother. But these effects eachothers.

Here is the situation:

> Project1 deployed , Project 2 doesn't work.
>
> Project2 deployed , Project 1 doesn't work.

How can I avoid it?

Comment: Check the ULS log during installation of the second solution. Probably some code or artifacts in the solution is not able to be run or created due to the first solution / project

Comment: In the logs when deploying both, there is no clue. When project1 deployed there is only logs about project1 during this job.

Comment: OK, i still think that the solutions are trying to create the same list or something like that. Whereby the last one installed fails due to a lack of error handling

Comment: Is it possible to creating the same list? Because they are different VS Sharepoint Projects. I'm looking more deeply into the logs :/